# INDIRECT gives #NUM! error for filtered off cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following formula

```
INDIRECT("X5:X"&AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$5:$A400))/SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($A$5,ROW($A$5:$A400)-ROW($A$5),0)),1))
```

The AGGREGATE functions returns 256, which is the row number of the last visible (unfiltered) row. The first unfiltered row is row 147. In other words, only rows from 147 to 256 are visible.

The INDIRECT function is supposed to give an array of values in X5:X256. It gives #NUM!. Upon further investigation, I found that for X5:X146, which are filtered off, the INDIRECT function returns #NUM!. After X146, which are visible, it gives the value in the cells.

My first question is: why does INDIRECT gives #NUM! for filtered off, invisible cells?

To circumvent the problem, I guess I could use something like this:

```
INDIRECT("X" & AGGREGATE(15,7....) & "X" & AGGREGATE(14,7....)
```

This would give only the visible range but I wonder if there is another way of doing it.

A much simplified version of the file can be downloaded here:

[sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6ql7xsg5o03fjc/tobeupload.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: My guess:  Something in your data (or possibly the array being created for `AGGREGATE`), or maybe even how you have entered the formula onto the sheet.  `INDIRECT("X5:X256")` returns a full array no matter if rows are filtered out or not.

Comment: Yes. INDIRECT("X5:X256") returns a full array that is what I want. I just don't know why the filtered cells return #NUM!.

Comment: @Joshua Re-read my comment and provide more information.

Comment: I have deleted row 256. So, now the filtered rows are up to 255. I filter the data by date. If only October is visible, hence, row 220 to 255, INDIRECT shows that rows 5 to 219 are #NUM!. If, however, January and October are visible, no #NUM! is observed. Those invisible cells, February till September, do not appear as #NUM!. If February and October are visible, then, only January rows are #NUM!. AGGREGATE is no problem because it is consistent in giving the correct row number of the last visible row.

Comment: When both January and October rows are visible, INDIRECT returns an array in which row 5 to row 222 are all 0 and that's the correct result. I got these results by highlighting the relevant portion of the formula in the formula bar and hit F9.

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. It might help you to provide information if you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And also consider that to make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question.

Comment: Possible to upload the file to this site?

Comment: No it is not.  You can upload to some public sharing site (eg:oneDrive, dropBox, etx) and then post a link here.

Comment: OK, I'll do that within 24 hrs.

Comment: Finally, I have managed to put the file on a file sharing site and added the link to the original post.

Comment: In `J5:J11` you have circular references, and those formulas return `#NUM!`.  Hence any cell referring to them will also return an error.  `INDIRECT("J5:Jn")` does not exclude filtered cells, so it will necessarily refer to them.

Comment: But the formula in those cells returns zero when the cells are visible.

Comment: When those cells are showing zero, then J192 shows -400,000.  Since there is a circular reference, sometimes they will return `#NUM!` and sometimes `0` depending on the calculation state.  If you unhide, and then recalculate individually, you can get them to return `0`.  But, when they are hidden, they are still returning `#NUM!`. I suppose if it is returning correct results when you feed it reliable data, you could just wrap those formulas in an `IFERROR(<your_formula>,0)`